# Can I rescan a wallet with bitcoin core in more than one session?

Tags: bitcoin-core, rescan

Since it takes long time, I want to close bitcoin core and continue later.

Will it continue from where it stopped, or do one must do the whole scan in one session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rescanblockchain` command/RPC to rescan in stages. Simply provide a start height and stop height, then next time, start from the previous place you left off. You can continue this until you've rescanned the entire chain.

You can use the `getwalletinfo` RPC to see the current rescan progress too. If the wallet is already scanning, you can use this to estimate which block height it is up to, and then resume from there using `rescanblockchain`.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I can't get to the RPC, since once bitcoin core is up it immediately starts rescanning and no menu ever appears.

Comment: Did you initiate the rescan, or did Bitcoin core do it automatically?

Comment: Automatically. I can’t even insert a password for that wallet. I can't do anything since there is no menu.   The bitcoin core version I have is 0.22